# What is the solution used to obtain a "two different scroll speed" in this website? (see the link inside)

Tags: javascript

here is the link http://2013.beatfilmfestival.ru/

We have two columns but scrolling the page they run with different speeds.

The column on the right seems to be the principal element of the page, I mean, its scroll is normal and not subjected to any kind of dynamic transformation. While fot he left column I see the "top" property that change its value while we scroll the page. It reminds me something similar to the parallax effect.

Let me know what do you think

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That's called parallax.

Comment: I always see the parallax effect applied to the background, not to an entire element. That's the reason why I had some doubts...

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Parallax Scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling). If you Google that term alongside JavaScript and/or jQuery - you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you reffer to is "parallax" effect. There are multiple ways and endless effect limited only by you imagination.

Technicaly, they are pretty same.
Try to look at this plugin, which can handle parallax scrolling on iOS/Android devices as well. https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a plugin/library to accomplish parallax, I would recommend [Stellar](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/). It's non-janky (if you use it properly), and easy to use.